# Memory Leak in NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, nsjsonserialization

I have started looking into memory leaks recently and I'm not able to figure out why JSON serialization is causing a leak.

```
class func convertDataToDictionary(resultData: NSData) -> [String:AnyObject]{
    do{
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(resultData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
        if json != nil{
            return json!
        }
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
    return [String:AnyObject]()
}
```

I'm using this function to convert NSData into a dictionary. I've also attached a screenshot of the leak.

[image]

This isn't causing any major issues with the app, but I'd still like to know why it's happening. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I m not seen any leaks here

Comment: Please check the screenshot below. It lists the leaked memory content.

Comment: Anbu is right. It's used memory, not a leak. Displaying "leaked" memory can never be 100% accurate.